# PhotonNetworking Unity Player Spawn Not Working Over Network

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript, photon

So I have a unity project im working on we are using photon networking I have attached an image of the structure of the player and the scripts associated with it. For some reason when i load two players they can't see each other.

I know if I don't disable the player, I will see both but the control will be all screwed up, however if I disable the scripts associated with each element of the character, and leave the character enabled like the tutorial said I can't select the scripts for some reason I can't figure out how to get to the components.
[image]

I do get a failed join in the console here is the output

```
Failed Join
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
NetworkManager:OnPhotonRandomJoinFailed() (at Assets/Game Assets/Prefab/Resources/Scripts/NetworkManager.cs:28)
UnityEngine.GameObject:SendMessage(String, Object, SendMessageOptions)
NetworkingPeer:SendMonoMessage(PhotonNetworkingMessage, Object[]) (at Assets/Photon Unity Networking/Plugins/PhotonNetwork/NetworkingPeer.cs:1865)
NetworkingPeer:OnOperationResponse(OperationResponse) (at Assets/Photon Unity Networking/Plugins/PhotonNetwork/NetworkingPeer.cs:1223)
ExitGames.Client.Photon.PeerBase:DeserializeMessageAndCallback(Byte[])
ExitGames.Client.Photon.EnetPeer:DispatchIncomingCommands()
ExitGames.Client.Photon.PhotonPeer:DispatchIncomingCommands()
PhotonHandler:Update() (at Assets/Photon Unity Networking/Plugins/PhotonNetwork/PhotonHandler.cs:83)
```

but then it joins and doesn't fail

```
Joined Room
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
NetworkManager:OnJoinedRoom() (at Assets/Game Assets/Prefab/Resources/Scripts/NetworkManager.cs:32)
UnityEngine.GameObject:SendMessage(String, Object, SendMessageOptions)
NetworkingPeer:SendMonoMessage(PhotonNetworkingMessage, Object[]) (at Assets/Photon Unity Networking/Plugins/PhotonNetwork/NetworkingPeer.cs:1865)
NetworkingPeer:OnEvent(EventData) (at Assets/Photon Unity Networking/Plugins/PhotonNetwork/NetworkingPeer.cs:1708)
ExitGames.Client.Photon.PeerBase:DeserializeMessageAndCallback(Byte[])
ExitGames.Client.Photon.EnetPeer:DispatchIncomingCommands()
ExitGames.Client.Photon.PhotonPeer:DispatchIncomingCommands()
PhotonHandler:Update() (at Assets/Photon Unity Networking/Plugins/PhotonNetwork/PhotonHandler.cs:83)
```

Here is my NetworkManager

```
    /*
    public Camera standbyCamera;*/
    // Use this for initialization
    SpawnSpot[] spawnSpots; 
    void Start () {
        Connect ();
        spawnSpots = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<SpawnSpot> ();
    }
    
    void Connect(){
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings ("1.0.0");
    }
    
    void OnGui(){
        Debug.Log ("OnGui" + PhotonNetwork.connectionStateDetailed.ToString ());
        GUILayout.Label (PhotonNetwork.connectionStateDetailed.ToString ());
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void OnJoinedLobby () {
        Debug.Log ("Joined Lobby");
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRandomRoom ();
    }
    void OnPhotonRandomJoinFailed(){
        Debug.Log ("Failed Join");
        PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom (null);
    }
    void OnJoinedRoom() {
        Debug.Log ("Joined Room");
        SpawnMyPlayer ();
    }
    void SpawnMyPlayer(){
        SpawnSpot mySpawnSpot = spawnSpots [ Random.Range (0, spawnSpots.Length) ];
        GameObject myPlayer = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate ("Player", mySpawnSpot.transform.position, mySpawnSpot.transform.rotation, 0);
        //standbyCamera.enabled = false;
        myPlayer.gameObject.SetActive (true);
        //((MonoBehaviour)myPlayer.GetComponent("CharacterController")).enabled = true;
        //((MonoBehaviour)myPlayer.GetComponent("CharMove")).enabled = true;


    
    }
}
```

New Development
If I join in unity and then join again with another player i get the following error

```
Received OnSerialization for view ID 2001. We have no such PhotonView! Ignored this if you're leaving a room. State: Joined
UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning(Object)
NetworkingPeer:OnSerializeRead(Hashtable, PhotonPlayer, Int32, Int16) (at Assets/Photon Unity Networking/Plugins/PhotonNetwork/NetworkingPeer.cs:3342)
NetworkingPeer:OnEvent(EventData) (at Assets/Photon Unity Networking/Plugins/PhotonNetwork/NetworkingPeer.cs:1758)
ExitGames.Client.Photon.PeerBase:DeserializeMessageAndCallback(Byte[])
ExitGames.Client.Photon.EnetPeer:DispatchIncomingCommands()
ExitGames.Client.Photon.PhotonPeer:DispatchIncomingCommands()
PhotonHandler:Update() (at Assets/Photon Unity Networking/Plugins/PhotonNetwork/PhotonHandler.cs:83)
```

I've changed the code a bit and it seems to be working except the camera

```
    SpawnSpot[] spawnSpots; 
    void Start () {
        Connect ();
        spawnSpots = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<SpawnSpot> ();
    }
    
    void Connect(){
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings ("1.0.0");
    }
    
    void OnGui(){
        Debug.Log ("OnGui" + PhotonNetwork.connectionStateDetailed.ToString ());
        GUILayout.Label (PhotonNetwork.connectionStateDetailed.ToString ());
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void OnJoinedLobby () {
        Debug.Log ("Joined Lobby");
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRandomRoom ();
    }
    void OnPhotonRandomJoinFailed(){
        Debug.Log ("Failed Join");
        PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom (null);
    }
    void OnJoinedRoom() {
        Debug.Log ("Joined Room");
        SpawnMyPlayer ();
    }
    public void SpawnMyPlayer(){
        SpawnSpot mySpawnSpot = spawnSpots [ Random.Range (0, spawnSpots.Length) ];
        GameObject myPlayer = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate ("Player", mySpawnSpot.transform.position, mySpawnSpot.transform.rotation, 0);
        //standbyCamera.enabled = false;
        myPlayer.gameObject.SetActive (true);
        //((MonoBehaviour)myPlayer.GetComponent("CharacterController")).enabled = true;
        ((MonoBehaviour)myPlayer.GetComponent("CharMove")).enabled = true;

        Transform[] allChildren = GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
        foreach (Transform child in allChildren) {
            ((MonoBehaviour)child.GetComponent("MouseLook")).enabled = true;
            child.transform.FindChild("Camera").gameObject.SetActive (true);
        }

        //myPlayer.transform.FindChild ("Camera").gameObject.SetActive (true);
    
    }
}
```

When I spawn the second character  it doesnt start the camera and im technically controlling the second character from the first characters camera.

As I keep coding away Ive come up with this

```
        spawnSpots = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<SpawnSpot> ();
    }
    
    void Connect(){
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings ("1.0.0");
    }
    
    void OnGui(){
        Debug.Log ("OnGui" + PhotonNetwork.connectionStateDetailed.ToString ());
        GUILayout.Label (PhotonNetwork.connectionStateDetailed.ToString ());
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void OnJoinedLobby () {
        Debug.Log ("Joined Lobby");
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRandomRoom ();
    }
    void OnPhotonRandomJoinFailed(){
        Debug.Log ("Failed Join");
        PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom (null);
    }
    void OnJoinedRoom() {
        Debug.Log ("Joined Room");
        SpawnMyPlayer ();
    }
    public void SpawnMyPlayer(){
        SpawnSpot mySpawnSpot = spawnSpots [ Random.Range (0, spawnSpots.Length) ];
        GameObject myPlayer = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate ("Player", mySpawnSpot.transform.position, mySpawnSpot.transform.rotation, 0);
        //standbyCamera.enabled = false;
        myPlayer.gameObject.SetActive (true);
        //((MonoBehaviour)myPlayer.GetComponent("CharacterController")).enabled = true;



        try
        {
            MouseLook mouseScript = myPlayer.GetComponentInChildren<MouseLook>();
            if(mouseScript != null)
            {
                mouseScript.enabled = true;
            }
            CharMove moveScript = myPlayer.GetComponentInChildren<CharMove>();
            if(moveScript != null)
            {
                moveScript.enabled = true;
            }
            CharacterController controlScript = myPlayer.GetComponentInChildren<CharacterController>();
            if(controlScript != null)
            {
                controlScript.enabled = true;
            }
            Camera childCam = myPlayer.GetComponentInChildren<Camera>();
            if(childCam != null)
            {
                childCam.enabled = true;
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            Debug.Log ("Error finding children");
        }


    
    }
}
```

So I don't get any errors but it doesn't find the child of Turret, PivotPoint and Enable its mouse look it only enables the turret mouse look.

Answer (score 0):

I have a answer that is in the `SpawnMyPlayer` function you set

```
GameObject myPlayer = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate ("Player", mySpawnSpot.transform.position, mySpawnSpot.transform.rotation, 0);
```

it has to be

```
GameObject myPlayer = (GameObject)PhotonNetwork.Instantiate ("Player", mySpawnSpot.transform.position, mySpawnSpot.transform.rotation, 0);
```

Also in the editor try adding a `Photon View` component :) 
Hope This Helps!